# for文で回しているリストをループ内で要素を削除してもリストが更新されない

Tags: python, python3

初歩の質問で申し訳ありません。
下記のようなコードで`List1`をfor文で回し、ループ内で`List1`の要素を削除後、
次のforループで削除された`List1`を使ってループを回したいです。

下記のコードではうまくいきません。
実行結果、期待したい動作について下記に示します。

わかりませんのでご教授お願いいたします。

```
import copy as cp

List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['○', '△', '□']]

save1 = cp.deepcopy(List1)
for i, row in enumerate(List1):
    print('for文頭：row = ' + str(row))
    if i == 0:
        save2 = []
        for j, s in enumerate(save1):
            if j != 1:
                save2.append(s)
        print('save2 = ' + str(save2))
    List1 = cp.deepcopy(save2)
```

**実行結果**

```
for文頭：row = ['a', 'b', 'c']
save2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['○', '△', '□']]
for文頭：row = ['x', 'y', 'z']
for文頭：row = ['○', '△', '□']
```

**期待したい動作**

```
for文頭：row = ['a', 'b', 'c']
save2 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['○', '△', '□']]
for文頭：row = ['○', '△', '□']
```

Comment: 「ループ内でList1の要素を削除」とはコードのどの部分を指していますか？

Comment: 多分動作を誤解されています。質問に`次のforループ`の処理が書かれていないので結果が明確化されていないのでしょう。`for i, row in enumerate(List1):`のループを終了した後の`List1`は望んだ結果になっています。例えば`for`ループの後で`print('for処理後：List1 = ', List1)`を実行してみれば分かるでしょう。

Comment: `List1`のループ中に `List1`を置き換える理由は何でしょう？
そのような構造のプログラムは避けるべきで, [for 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.9/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)の注釈部分にも記されてます。
何らかの目的があっての 内部で内容書き換える構造ならば, それを記すことで回避策の回答が得られるかも

Comment: あるいは質問に`次のforループ`とあるのは`for i, row in enumerate(List1):ループの次の回`でしょうか？ その場合 @oriri さん紹介のリンク先にあるように、`expression_list の結果に対するイテレータが生成されます。`とあって、そのイテレータは`List1`とは別物(内部的にdeepcopy()したのと同等)？になっていると思われます。なので`for i, row in enumerate(List1):`ループの中で`List1`のオブジェクトを変更しても`forループのイテレータ`には影響が無く、動作は変化しないと考えられます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。@kunifさんの解説で理解できたと思います。``List1``の要素を削除してそれを``forループのイテレータ``に使う繰り返しの処理は書けたりするのでしょうか。

Comment: 変更を行った時点でいったんループを終了して、何個目まで済んだかの情報と共に別の新しいループを作成して別の処理を続けるといったことが考えられますが、無駄に複雑な処理になりそうなので、そうしたことは行わずに処理全体を見直した方が良いでしょう。